# How to call a "symbol" in Adobe Illustrator using Java script?

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-illustrator

I am trying to call a symbol that I created named "TMark" and position it in the document using the coordinates so far I have the script below but no success.

```
var doc              = app.activeDocument;
var markLayer        = app.activeDocument.layers.add()
markLayer.name       = "MARKS"
var groupAll         = app.activeDocument.groupItems.add()
var tmark            = app.activeDocument.symbols.getByName("TMark")
tmark.position       = [300, 300]
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize the documents [`SymbolItems.add()`](https://illustrator-scripting-guide.readthedocs.io/jsobjref/SymbolItems/#symbolitems-add) method to create an instance of the specified symbol and then position it.

For instance:

```js
var doc = app.activeDocument;

// 1. Create a new layer
var markLayer = doc.layers.add();
markLayer.name = "MARKS";

// 2. Get a reference to the symbol
var tmark = doc.symbols.getByName("TMark");

// 3. Place the symbol on the Artboard and position it.
doc.symbolItems.add(tmark).position = [300, -300];
```